# Why is the output different to what the input is?

Tags: python

I'm working on my first project and so far everything is good but I noticed a problem, first of all here is my code:

```
#name generator
import random

#clear console
import os

def cls():
    os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')

#import from txt file:
with open('nameGenerator.txt') as file:
    suggestions = file.readlines()
    suggestions = [s.strip() for s in suggestions]

suggest5 = random.choices(suggestions, k = 5)

def startSuggest():
  global nameSuggest1
  nameSuggest1 = input("your name is " + nameSuggest + " || thank you, you can now begin your game! \n press any key to continue:")

def start():
  global start
  start = input("your name is " + name + " || thank you, you can now begin your game! \n press any key to continue:")
 
name = input("What would you like your name to be? \n if you are unsure about what you want your name to be please type \"suggest\"  \n")

if name != "suggest":
  start()
elif name == "suggest": 
  print("here are some of my syggestions: \n")
  print(', '.join(suggest5))
  nameSuggest = input("Please pick one and enter the username: \n")
  startSuggest()

#would u rather question
cls()
if name:
  dollarQuestion = input("Question for " + name + " would you like $1,000,000 or $0.01 every single day for thirty days?\n")
elif nameSuggest:
  dollarQuestion = input("Question for " + nameSuggest + "would you like $1,000,000 or $0.01 every single day for thirty days?\n")

if dollarQuestion in ("$1,000,000", "$1000000", "1000000", "1,000,000"):
    print("great! you have recieved your $1,000,000")
elif dollarQuestion in ("$0.01", "0.01"):
      TotalPenny = 0.01 *(2**30)
      if TotalPenny > 1000000:
        print("that's nice, you have recived a total of $" + str(round(TotalPenny, 3)) +    " that's a win for you." )
      elif TotalPenny < 1000000:
        print("that's bad, you have recived a total of $" + str(round(TotalPenny, 3)) + " that's a loss for you." )
else:
      print("please try again but this time pick a valid amount")
```

everything works perfectly fine but I noticed when my first input is "suggest" it gives me my suggestions and it also outputs `your name is test || thank you, you can now begin your game!  press any key to continue:` it works perfectly fine up until now but the problem is once the second question comes this is the output:

```
Question for suggest would you like $1,000,000 or $0.01 every single day for thirty days?
```

why does that happen, why is it outputting "suggest" but not the data inputted after the suggest feature?

Comment: For starters, don't name global variables the same as funcitons (and you shouldn't need global variables here anyway). Secondly, can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: Get rid of all the `global` variables, they're going to do nothing but confuse you (which is why most people will tell you to avoid them at all costs even if they seem useful -- and they don't even seem useful here).

Comment: When your `if` and `elif` conditions are exact opposites, you should use `if` and `else`.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have these as global variables cause I was testing out different solutions to fix a problem I had earlier but I ended up fixing them without needing any global variables, I just forgot to make them local again my bad

Comment: `if name:` will succeed when the user enters `suggest`.

Comment: @Barmar thank you! I just changed my "if name:" to "if name != "suggest"" and that fixed.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just put the user's response to the suggestions in the `name` variable, so the rest of the code doesn't care whether it was their original response or came from a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simplified version of this code.  Note that the question part does not actually test the thing that the question implies that it tests.

One thing to pay attention to is that if you want to give information to a function (e.g. the name you want to pass to `start`), you should make it a parameter to the function, rather than trying to pull the variable directly from the calling scope.

There's also no benefit to having multiple functions that do the same thing (e.g. your `start` and `startSuggest`), or for that matter two different variables that hold the same information (e.g. `name` and `nameSuggest`).  Putting the player's name into the variable `name` no matter what means you don't need to have the question part of your code check to see if it should be looking at `name` or `nameSuggest`.

```
import os
import random


def cls():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')


# import from txt file:
with open('nameGenerator.txt') as file:
    suggestions = [s.strip() for s in file.readlines()]


def start(name: str) -> None:
    print(f"your name is {name} || thank you, you can now begin your game!")
    print("press any key to continue:")
    input()


print("What would you like your name to be?")
print('if you are unsure about what you want your name to be please type "suggest"')
name = input()

if name == "suggest":
    print("here are some of my syggestions: \n")
    print(', '.join(random.choices(suggestions, k=5)))
    print("Please pick one and enter the username:")
    name = input()

start(name)

# would u rather question
cls()
dollarQuestion = input("Question for " + name + " would you like $1,000,000 or $0.01 every single day for thirty days?\n")
if dollarQuestion in ("$1,000,000", "$1000000", "1000000", "1,000,000"):
    print("great! you have recieved your $1,000,000")
elif dollarQuestion in ("$0.01", "0.01"):
    total = 0.01 * (2**30)  # this is not the same as a penny a day for thirty days, it's a MUCH bigger number!
    print(f"that's nice, you have recived a total of ${round(total, 3)} that's a win for you.")
else:
    print("please try again but this time pick a valid amount")
```